# PHP: while loop is infinite

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

```
<?php 
$animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10)
{
    echo "<li>$animals[$i]</li>";
}
?>
```

I just wanna see the pig, chicken, cow and snake in list item..
but what happen is it just looping the word pig infinitely...

Comment: Wow, does it really need 4 exact same answers?

Comment: As @AnkurTiwari pointed out, `$i++;` is missing, and you should modify your loop statement to `while ($i < count($animals)) { ... }`. The `count($animals)` statement was also in Ankur's answer, but there wasn't any explanation to that or `$i++;`. `$i++` adds one to `$i` so that `$i` doesn't forever stay at `0`. Also, to prevent out-of-bounds undefined behavior evils, I used `count($animals)`. Don't go undefined. [Don't do it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31016660/2089760)

Comment: @DDPWNAGE Yes, completely agree with you thanks for your explanation. have updated my answer.

Comment: $i always below than 10 that's why it's doing infinite loop. You should add increment inside while statement to stop the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding increment to `$i`. You can add increment to `$i` by adding `$i++` in your `while` loop.

```
<?php 
$animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10)
{
    if (isset($animals[$i]))
    {
        echo "<li>$animals[$i]</li>";
    }
    $i++
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you do that without using $i++?

Comment: Check below code @Sunny have posted code without while. Without changing $i variable it is not possible to break the loop.

Comment: I have a similar code but it is not pulling all of the assoc data with this [id] Can someone help take a look and see what is wrong with this? $res = $dbCon->query("SELECT * FROM listingAmenities WHERE listingId = '$listingId' ORDER BY id DESC");
     while($data = $res->fetch_assoc()){
      $propertyAmenities = $data['propertyAmenities'];
      echo "<span class=\"facBtn\"> $propertyAmenities <a href=\"\" class=\"removeFac\" > remove </a></span><br>";   IT is not looping the items under the same listingId until there are no more available. It is only displaying 1, the first one.

Comment: Make sure you have more entries under same `listingId`

Answer (score 2):

this should loop through the array by using `$i++` which increments the `$i` variable by one.

```
<?php 
 $animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
 $i = 0;
while ($i < 4) {
    echo "<li>$animals[$i]</li>";
    $i++;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't just post code, tell us what you changed and improved.

Comment: can you do that without If statement? what I mean is just using while.

Answer (score 1):

I have added $i++; which is increment the value of $i by one each time in the loop, so we are able to display each element of array also find length of array in initial to avoid array out-of-bound problem.

```
<?php 
 $animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
 $i = 0;
 $len = count($animals);
    while ($i < $len) 
    {
       echo "<li>$animals[$i]</li>";
       $i++;
    }

 ?>
```

Initially count the length of array and then iterate the loop according to length.

Comment: Don't just post code, tell us what you changed and improved.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use foreach to do this

```
$animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
foreach($animals as $animal)
echo "<li>{$animal}</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
  $i = 0;
  $max = sizeof($animals);
  while ($i < max) {
    echo "<li>$animals[$i]</li>";
    i++;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i do like a while loop, so here's one more for the mix! :)

```
<?php
$animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
while ($animal = next($animals)) {
    echo "<li>$animal[$i]</li>";
}
?>
```

this uses [next()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) to get each value of the array, this returns false when its gets to the end of the array terminating the `while` loop. You don't need to control getting elements of the array using `$i` and you don't need extra `if` statements inside the loop checking if your element exists

Answer (score 0):

You haven't incremented the `$i` value so it is always `$i = 0;` so it always under 10.

Add `$i++` to increment it to avoid this, but with this code you get another new problem, because the array is having only 3 elements and you are using 10 in the while loop.

```
<?php 
    $animals = array('pig', 'chicken', 'cow', 'snake');
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 10)
    {
        echo "<li>$animals[$i]</li>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```